# How to extend a .desktop file for adding new Actions?

Tags: gnome, libreoffice, .desktop

I want to add some extra `Actions` to the shortcut that starts *LibreOffice Writer*, for quickly opening some of my documents by right clicking on the *Favorite* icon of *Writer*.

To do this, I copied the file `/usr/share/applications/libreoffice-writer.desktop` to my `~/.local/share/applications/` with a different name, simplified its contents, changed its `Name=` and `Comment=` lines, and added some new `Actions=`. (I do *not* want to change the system-wide original desktop file, since my additions should be done per user basis.)

The new shortcut appears under *Activities* and menus and I can start an instance of Writer by selecting it. However, after *Writer* starts, the right-click menu of its icon is still the original (system-wide) one: My extra `Actions` do not appear. And if I add it to *Favorites*, not any of my new `Actions` are added.

What is the correct method of adding some *new Actions* to a system-wide desktop file?

Note: My new desktop file is named `~/.local/share/applications/libreoffice-writer-xxx.desktop` and has contents like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Terminal=false
Icon=libreoffice-writer
Type=Application
Exec=libreoffice --writer %U
Name=LibreOffice Writer Shortcuts
Comment=Local copy of desktop file
StartupNotify=true
Actions=NewDocument1;doc1;doc2;

[Desktop Action doc1]
Name=Open doc1.odt
Exec=libreoffice --writer /home/xxx/Documents/doc1.odt

[Desktop Action doc2]
Name=Open doc2.odt
Exec=libreoffice --writer /home/xxx/Documents/doc2.odt

[Desktop Action NewDocument1]
Name=Start New Document
Exec=libreoffice --writer
```

Comment: A similar question is this: **How can I configure Thunar (file manager) to start by displaying a specific directory like: /home/my_user/Documents/my_office_docs?**

Comment: Try *not* changing the name of the copy of the .desktop file in your .local/shara/applications folder. I think the rename is causing the undesired behaviour.

Comment: Thanks, @vanadium. That should be the correct method.

Comment: Thanks for testing. I accordingly added my comment as a full answer to your question. Your question is a good example on how to customize the right click actions. The only issue was indeed this renaming.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are describing the good approach on how to edit a .desktop file in order to add custom actions. It is also good practice to work on a copy of the file in your .local/share/applications folder. This way, the changes are only in effect for yourself or other users that use that copy, and also ensures the changes will not be overwritten by an update.

Your specific issue, however, is where you are renaming your local copy. To prevent that the system wide .desktop file settings are used, make sure your local copy **has the same file name** as the system wide .desktop file. Only then will it fully replace for the system wide .desktop file.