# shortcut "calc" meant to open calculator always open libreoffice ( first position in search )

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, calculator

When I search for an app with the windows keyboard key, I enter `calc` to open calculator, and I always have 2 results, `LibreOffice`, and `Calculator`. LibreOffice is always first, and I always open LibreOffice, which is not what I want.

This is a many many times error, does anybody know how to prevent it ? Maybe changing the order of the 2 apps, or disabling LibreOffice for this search.... I don't know how to do none of them.

Comment: How about setting a key (such as F12) to invoke the calculator?

Comment: I am used to write calc, I would think about it if this is not possible to achieve

Comment: You need to modify the related `.desktop` file for _LO Calc_ and change the application's "name" to something else...

Comment: ooo it worked, I changed Name=LibreOffice Calc to Name=LibreOffice and now calculator appears in first position ! Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify the related `.desktop` file for *LibreOffice Calc* and change the application's "name" to something else.

Some hints on this process may be found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1127870/how-to-extend-a-desktop-file-for-adding-new-actions).