# Adding a custom menu to the status bar

Tags: gnome, statusbar

I would like to add a custom menu to the status bar, containing arbitrary items of my own choosing, such as scripts etc.

There is an extension to add the full Applications menu; that's NOT what I want. Instead, I want to add an extra icon to the status bar, such that when you click on it, it shows list of items in a menu that I will have defined, and clicking on one executes a command.

I imagined this should be an easy thing to achieve but couldn't find documentation on it, only on adding launcher items which also isn't what I was after. Any ideas?

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04, but guess this could apply to any GNOME-based distro.

Comment: Can you consider this as a starting point? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1127870/how-to-extend-a-desktop-file-for-adding-new-actions

Comment: Have you looked into "Alacarte" perhaps?