# Dynamic actions on right clicking the application icon in the docker

Tags: 20.04, gnome

I wanted to add some dynamic option for my application similar to the firefox application that shows the open tabs under open windows(as can be seen in the image below).

I have followed this link : [How to extend a .desktop file for adding new Actions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1127870/how-to-extend-a-desktop-file-for-adding-new-actions)  and I am aware on how to add the static options but I m not able to figure out how to add these dynamic options.

Any help on how is this being done?

[image]